# Отображение объекта при нажатии

Tags: javascript

не могу понять в чём проблема, хочу чтобы при нажатии объект с классом 'hidden' отображался на странице.

```js
var x=  document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
 for(var i=0; i<x.length;i++){
   x[i].style.display="none"
 }
var y=document.getElementsByClassName('show-all');
for(var j=0; j<y.length;j++){
  y[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
  x[j].style.display="block"
  })
}
```

```css
.show-all{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
<li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
<li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>

</ul>
<p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
<div>
<ul>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
<li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>

</ul>
<p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
<div>
<ul>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>

</ul>
<p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none"
}
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('show-all');
for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
  y[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.closest("div").querySelectorAll(".hidden").forEach(item => item.style.display = "");
  })
}
```

```css
.show-all {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>

  </ul>
  <p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>

  </ul>
  <p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>

  </ul>
  <p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
```

```
this.closest("div").querySelectorAll(".hidden").forEach(item => item.style.display = "");
```

`this` - от элемента, на котором произошло событие

`.closest("div")` - поднимаемся к ближайшему родителю типа `div`

`querySelectorAll(".hidden")` - в котором находим все элементы с классом `hidden`

каждому из которых очищаем `style.display`

Comment: this.closest("div").querySelectorAll(".hidden").forEach(item => item.style.display = "");       Можете пожалуйста объяснить эту строку @Igor

Comment: в этом случае почему нам нужен  closest("div")?

Comment: @Asking потому что я подумал (так как кнопок `show-all` несколько), что Вы хотите показать спрятанные элементы только в том родителе, в котором находится кнопка

Comment: forEach.function(item => item.style.display = "block"))  - этот код будет идентичен вашему? Можете пожалуйста объяснить его.

Comment: @Asking Хм, что тут объяснять? Я очищаю свойство `style.display`, а Вы присваиваете ему значение `"block"`.

Comment: нет, могли бы вы объяснить как работает именно этот код 'forEach(item => item', в частности меня интересует часть: 'item => item''., спрашиваю потому что я не видел до этого такой формулировки. Спасибо

Comment: @Asking это в данном случае то же самое, что `.forEach(function(item) { ... });`. Читайте: "javascript", "стрелочные функции".

Answer (score 2):

Можно так.

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var li = e.target.previousElementSibling.querySelectorAll("li.hidden");
    for (var x = 0; x < li.length; x++) {
      li[x].style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="hidden">3</li>
  <li class="hidden">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button>Show all ul #1</button>

<ul>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li class="hidden">8</li>
  <li class="hidden">9</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>

<button>Show all ul #2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Подразумеваю, что показываться должны лишь элементы входящие в блок с кнопкой.

Так же советую ознакомиться со статьёй на хабре, описывающей разницу между [var, let и const](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/420359/)

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none"
}

let y = document.getElementsByClassName('show-all');

for (let j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {

  y[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
    let x = y[j].parentNode.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "block"
    }
    
  })
  
}
```

```css
.show-all {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
  </ul>
  <p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
  </ul>
  <p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Lorem</li>
  </ul>
  <p class='show-all'>show</p>
</div>
```